# Embedding and configuring mysql db .net installer to use in asp.net application

Tags: .net, database, installation

how can i install and configure mysql db with .net installer?

is there is any better db available with Zero installation and zero configuration that i can use it with .net installer ?

Abdul khaliq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there is any better db available
>   with Zero installation and zero
>   configuration that i can use it with
>   .net installer ?

SQL Server Compact, or SQLite.

Comment: first question has more priority than the second one :)